# Apply polymorphic function in a GHC plugin

Tags: haskell, ghc

I would like to write a GHC plugin which "adds a hook" to each function. Say I want to apply a function `addHook` of type `Ord a => (a -> b) -> a -> b` to the right-hand side of each function binding, transforming

```
foo = [RHS]
```

into

```
foo = addHook [RHS]
```

This works fine if I'm only interested in adding hooks to functions of type `Int -> Int`, in which case I make `addHook` also to have type `(Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int`, and invoke `mkCoreApp [AddHook] [RHS]` and bind it to `foo` in my GHC plugin.

However, if I want `addHook` to be polymorphic as described above, the transformed GHC Core for an `Int -> Int` function should look like

```
foo = addHook @ GHC.Types.Int @ GHC.Types.Int GHC.Classes.$fOrdInt [RHS]
```

Notice that there should be some type information attached, but I cannot find a way to construct these in the plugin, and GHC panics without those. Any suggestion would be appreciated.